# How to split domain info from username in PHP

Tags: php

PHP is pulling the user id as `"domain\username"` through `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` 
I am looking to be able to echo just the username in the html.

Comment: `explode` is one of the most useful functions in PHP.

Comment: `$v = explode('\', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']); end($v);` will get usersname, make sure to validate it though before trusting it.

Comment: What is inside `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`? Please give an example.

Answer (score 2):

You want to extract `username` from the following string:

```
domain\username
```

You can use [strrchr()](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) for that:

```
echo substr(strrchr($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'], '\\'), 1);
```

*You need an additional `substr()` to skip the first backslash*

Or using `explode()`:

```
echo end(explode('\\', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']));
```

*Slightly more memory intensive, but probably won't matter in your case*

Comment: @Chris No problem, if this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark next to this answer.

Answer (score -1):

What's the structure of your URL? What CMS? What platform? There may be a function to get it within the core.

However, you could use $_GET, as such

```
http://www.domain.com/?username=John


<?php 
$username = $_GET['username'];
// If you're on PHP 5.2+, use:
$username = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>
```